# Azure Cli in a container job

Tags: azure-devops, containers, jobs, azure-cli

I created a docker container using Dockerfile.

```
&& apk add --virtual=build gcc libffi-dev musl-dev openssl-dev make python3-dev \
&& pip3 --no-cache-dir install azure-cli==${AZURE_CLI_VERSION} \
```

but still the Azure DevOps container job fail with the error

> ## [error]Azure CLI 2.x is not installed on this machine.

Can you please let me know is there anything i can do with path or do I need to install Azure cli by some other means ??

Comment: Which is the task being used here?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT : I am using a Container Job which is running a container on ubuntu hosted agent. This container has the azure cli installed in it at path:
bash-5.0# which az
/usr/bin/az

But the task fails :
##[debug]which 'az'
##[debug]not found
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'az'.

My task looks like:
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Push helm charts to ACR'
  inputs:
     azureSubscription: ''
     scriptLocation: inlineScript
     inlineScript: |
        az acr helm push *

Comment: According to your previous comment, this issue occurred on your AzurecLI@1 task, correct? As normal, this task will trying to find the az.cmd from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd'**. Could you update the completed dockerfile? Also, please also update with how your pipeline looks like? Then we could reproduce that quickly and find the cause.

Comment: Just want check, how's my colleague's solution. Is it work for you? Don't hesitate to leave comment below if you still has any puzzle:-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sample command from my pipeline and az seems to work fine. This is the yaml that I tested with Azure CLI task version 1:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xxxxx
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az acr list'
```

As shown in the output of the task execution, the Azure CLI is intalled at: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd**

[image: Azure CLI task output]

If you are still blocked, please post the details of the steps and tasks used in your build pipeline and we can troubleshoot further.